# Ansible "template error" using variable in formatted string

Tags: python, ansible

This ansible task is supposed to check whether an specific version of an npm package is installed and, if not, install it. The `when` condition I am using involves a formatted string with a defined variable, `pm2_version`, yet for some reason my attempt to use that variable in the test is causing an error.

I expect that the expression `f'pm2@{pm2_version}'` should create a formatted string, but clearly that expectation is incorrect. What is the correct way to use a variable here?

Here are the relevant tasks:

```yaml
- name: List installed packages
  shell: 'npm list -g --depth=0'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.nvm/versions/node/{{node_version}}/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
  register: npm_package_list

- name: Install pm2
  shell: 'npm i -g pm2@{{pm2_version}}'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  environment:
    PATH: '{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.nvm/versions/node/{{node_version}}/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}'
    when: npm_package_list.stdout.find(f'pm2@{pm2_version}') == -1
```

But running the playbook, I get the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'npm_package_list.stdout.find(f'pm2@{pm2_version}') == -1' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'string'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is an anti-pattern in Ansible.
Ansible is based on [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency), that is to say, in your case, if the npm package is already installed at the version requested version, Ansible will do nothing, and return you an `ok` status while it will return you a `changed` status in case it had to install it.

But for this, you have to use the dedicated [`npm` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/npm_module.html):

```yaml
- npm:
    name: "{{ 'pm2@%s' | format(pm2_version) }}"
    global: yes
    executable: >- 
      {{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.nvm/versions/node/{{ node_version }}/bin/npm
```

---

Still, your two (maybe three) issues, here, are:

- Jinja is not implementing all the functionalities of Python, so there are features that will not work, like `find` on a string
- For the same reason, f-strings are not supported
- (Possibly a typo in the question) Your `when` close is wrongly indented.

In order to find a substring in a string, you can use the [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.in), or in your case `not in` test.
In order to have a f-string formatting, you can use the [`format` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.format), or just use a string concatenation `~`.

So, your condition should look like:

```yaml
when: "'pm2@%s' | format(pm2_version) not in npm_package_list.stdout"
```

or

```yaml
when: "'pm2@' ~ pm2_version not in npm_package_list.stdout"
```

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: "'pm2@%s' | format(pm2_version) not in npm_package_list.stdout"
  vars:
    pm2_version: 1.2.4
    npm_package_list:
      stdout: pm2@1.2.3
```

Which yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  '''pm2@%s'' | format(pm2_version) not in npm_package_list.stdout': true
```

Comment: Using Ansible's `npm` module looks like the way to go here, but isn't setting up a test and using the install command only when the module is not already installed a reasonable way to avoid making it an anti-pattern?

Comment: Not fully, you won't have an `ok` or `changed` state you will have an `ok` or `skipped` stated, which, if I was to run someone else playbook, would get me wondering if this is really the purposed behaviour.